# Google Pay transaction history using API calls

Tags: api, web-development-server, google-pay

I want to build a expense tracker website that can automatically take the transactions from my google pay transactions and segregate it on the basis of description about the payment I have given(Eg. food,Stationary,clothing,party,ect). How can I use the Google Pay API to do so?

I tried to read about this but could not find any relevent solution for the above.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.